# Mongodb use native openssl in centos

Tags: openssl, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm not sure what I am missing in this.

MongoDB advises that as of v4.0, it uses the native OpenSSL libraries; but no matter what, my build or install from the repository, the OpenSSL binary appears to be part of the install and is always version 1.0.1e.

I want to use another OpenSSL version, which is installed and accessible on my machine, so that I can interact with an external source via PKCS11 for external generation and protection of keys.

This doesn't seem to be part of Mongo's documentation at all, just that native libraries are used; I think that as long as I can feed in an openssl.cnf file I could have the functionality I need, but I can't find the right commands to do this either.

Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it essentially asks how to build mongodb against some local version of a specific library. While in this case this specific library is openssl the question by itself is about the build process which is unrelated to security.

Comment: I agree with @SteffenUllrich.

Comment: Understood. I'll ask in another community.